# SearchView is not editable

Tags: android, xml, searchview

Using libs MaterialDesign SerachView, on usual searchview the same problem. When clickin on searchview button it is opening and shows hint, but i can't edit it and earlier it just show keyboard but now it isn't shows even.

```
public class  ListOfFriends extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final int ADD_NEW_FRIEND_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EXIT_APP_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private Manager imService = null;
    private FriendListAdapter friendAdapter;
    private DynamicListView list;
    SublimeNavigationView snv;
    private StorageManipulater localstoragehandler;
    private Cursor dbCursor;
    private TextView nameofusr;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    private static final String TOOLBAR_TEXTVIEW_FIELD_NAME = "mTitleTextView";
    private static final String TOOLBAR_NAV_BTN_FIELD_NAME = "mNavButtonView";
    private TextView tvToolbarTitle;
    public String ownusername = new String();
    private static EditText mFriendUserNameText;
    private MaterialSearchView mSearchView;
    private ImageButton btnToolbarButton;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private TextView empty;

    public String decryptMes(String mes,String s1,String s2) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Log.i("DECR  ", mes+s1+s2);
        ArrayList <String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add(s1);
        list1.add(s2);
        Collections.sort(list1);

        s1 = list1.get(0) + list1.get(1);
        list1.clear();

        try {
            String messageAfterDecrypt = AESCrypt.decrypt(s1, mes);
            Log.i(" Descryption: ", messageAfterDecrypt);
            return messageAfterDecrypt;
        }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){
            Log.i(" Descryption: ", "ERROR");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
            //handle error - could be due to incorrect password or tampered encryptedMsg
        }

    }


    //список друзей
    private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Swappable
    {

        String msg = "";
        String datemsg = "";

        boolean flag = false;


        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;//имя друга
            TextView mes;
            TextView date;
            TextView newmes;
            View status;
            LinearLayout llRemoveCheckMark;
            ImageView icon;//статус
            boolean flag = false;
            int unrmesg = 0;

        }
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mAvatar;

        private Context context;

        private InfoOfFriend friends[];
        String text = "";


        public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            mAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_48dp);
            Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "CONSTRUKTER");


        }

        private void clearRemoveModes() {
            for (InfoOfFriend item : friends){
                item.isRemoveMode = false;
            }
        }

        public void removeItems(HashSet<Integer> financeItemsToRemove) {
            //TODO
            }


        public void saveOrder() {
        //TODO
        }

        public void orderByAlphabet() {
            //TODO
        }
        //сеттер
        public void setFriendList(InfoOfFriend[] friends)

        {
            this.friends = friends;
        }

        public void setFriendNew(String name, String newmsg, String newdate)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                if(friends[i].equals(name))
                {
                    msg = newmsg;
                    datemsg = newdate;
                    break;}
            }

        }

//получаем количество
        public int getCount() {

            return friends.length;
        }

//выбираем друга
        public InfoOfFriend getItem(int position) {

            return friends[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return getItem(position).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public void swapItems(int i1, int i2) {
//          Collections.swap(friends, i1, i2);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



            Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "GETVIEW");
            InfoOfFriend friend = getItem(position);
            ViewHolder holder;



            dbCursor = localstoragehandler.get(friend.userName, MessagingService.USERNAME );


            Log.i("username", friend.userName);
            Log.i("meserv username", MessagingService.USERNAME);


            if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                dbCursor.moveToLast();
            }

            Log.i("CURSOR!!!!!!!", String.valueOf(dbCursor.getCount()));




            //TODO затем при получении сообщения (flag!!)

            //localstoragehandler.close();

            if (convertView == null )
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_list_screen, null);

                // создает ViewHolder и хранит ссылки на два дочерних view  с которыми хотим связать данные
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
                holder.mes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
                holder.status = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                if(!msg.isEmpty()) holder.newmes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newmes);
                holder.llRemoveCheckMark = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llRemoveCheckMark);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }   
            else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.date.setText("");
            holder.mes.setText("");
                if(dbCursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
                    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    Date d = null;


                    try {
                        if(msg.isEmpty())d = format.parse(dbCursor.getString(4));
                        else d = format.parse(datemsg);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // привязка данных
//                  if (unrmesg != 0) {
//                      holder.newmes.setText(unrmesg);
//                      holder.newmes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                  }
                    holder.date.setText((DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(ListOfFriends.this, d
                                    .getTime(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS,
                            DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, 0)));

                    if(msg.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Log.w("msg",  dbCursor.getString(3));
                        Log.w("2",  friend.userName);
                        Log.w("3",  MessagingService.USERNAME);
                        try {
                            holder.mes.setText(decryptMes(dbCursor.getString(3),MessagingService.USERNAME,friend.userName)   );
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.mes.setText(msg);
                        holder.newmes.setText("1");
                        holder.newmes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                    holder.date.setText("");
                    holder.mes.setText("");
                }


            holder.text.setText(friend.userName);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mAvatar);
            holder.status.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(friend.status == InfoStatus.ONLINE ? R.color.main_color_green : R.color.gray_light));



             msg = "";
             datemsg = "";
             flag = false;


            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public class MessageReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver  {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i("Broadcast receiver ", "received a message");
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            if (extra != null)
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();



                if (action.equals(MessagingService.FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED))
                {
                    // taking friend List from broadcast
                    //String rawFriendList = extra.getString(FriendInfo.FRIEND_LIST);
                    //FriendList.this.parseFriendInfo(rawFriendList);
                    ListOfFriends.this.updateData(ControllerOfFriend.getFriendsInfo(),
                                                ControllerOfFriend.getUnapprovedFriendsInfo());

                }
                else if (action.equals(MessagingService.TAKE_MESSAGE))
                {
                    String username = extra.getString(InfoOfMessage.USERID);
                String message = extra.getString(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGETEXT);
                String time = extra.getString(InfoOfMessage.SENDT);

                    friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }
        }

    };
    public MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver();

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {          
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder)service).getService();      

            InfoOfFriend[] friends = ControllerOfFriend.getFriendsInfo(); //imService.getLastRawFriendList();
            if (friends != null) {              
                ListOfFriends.this.updateData(friends, null); // parseFriendInfo(friendList);
            }

            setTitle("Telekilogramm");
            //nameofusr.setText(imService.getUsername());
            ownusername = imService.getUsername();
            if(ownusername!=null) nameofusr.setText(ownusername);


        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {          
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(ListOfFriends.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_friends);

        snv = (SublimeNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        nameofusr = (TextView) (snv.getHeaderView()).findViewById(R.id.tvNamePlate);

        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,null,
                R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        empty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty2);
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        mSearchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mSearchView.setVoiceSearch(true);
        mSearchView.setEnabled(true);

        mSearchView.setCursorDrawable(R.drawable.color_cursor_white);
        mSearchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });

        mSearchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                //Do some magic
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //Do some magic
            }
        });

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }



        localstoragehandler = new StorageManipulater(ListOfFriends.this);


        if (list == null) {

            list = (DynamicListView) findViewById(R.id.listfr);
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(ListOfFriends.this);
            friendAdapter.setFriendList(ControllerOfFriend.getFriendsInfo());

            list.setAdapter(friendAdapter);
            list.enableDragAndDrop();


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                                                Intent i = new Intent(ListOfFriends.this, PerformingMessaging.class);
                                                InfoOfFriend friend = friendAdapter.getItem(position);
                                                i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.USERNAME, friend.userName);
                                                i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.PORT, friend.port);
                                                i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.IP, friend.ip);
                                                startActivity(i);


                                            }
                                        }
            );
        }

        snv.setNavigationMenuEventListener(new OnNavigationMenuEventListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationMenuEvent(Event event,
                                                 SublimeBaseMenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (event) {
                    case CHECKED:
                        Log.i("", "Item checked");
                        break;
                    case UNCHECKED:
                        Log.i("", "Item unchecked");
                        break;
                    case GROUP_EXPANDED:
                        Log.i("", "Group expanded");
                        break;
                    case GROUP_COLLAPSED:
                        Log.i("", "Group collapsed");
                        break;
                    default:
                        menuItem.setChecked(!menuItem.isChecked());
                        break;
                }
                if(id == R.id.addfriendMenu){
                    showDialog(0);
                return true;
                }

                if(id == R.id.Unapr_fr) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ListOfFriends.this, WaitingListFriends.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if(id == R.id.settings) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ListOfFriends.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if(id == R.id.feedback) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mostwanted007@mail.ru"});
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback TgM");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Привет, твое приложение безупречно!");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


                if(id == R.id.share) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    String textToSend = "Привет, я использую TgM для обмена сообщениями, добавь меняЮ мой ник" + ownusername;
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToSend);
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Описание действия"));
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if(id == R.id.help) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListOfFriends.this);
                    builder.setTitle("О приложении")
                            .setMessage("TgM\n" +
                                    "Приложение для защищенного обмена сообщениями\n" +
                                    "Разработчик: Студент гр. ПО-21 Гудин Е.Р.\"")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setNegativeButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }

                if(id == R.id.exit) {
                    imService.exit();
                finish();
                return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });


    }
    public void updateData(InfoOfFriend[] friends, InfoOfFriend[] unApprovedFriends)
    {

        if (friends != null) {
            Log.w("DRDRDRDRDRDR", "hgjhgjghgjhgjhgjhgjhgh");
            friendAdapter.setFriendList(friends);
            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            friendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        Log.w("DRDRDRDRDRDR", "NO");
        if (unApprovedFriends != null) 
        {
            NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (unApprovedFriends.length > 0)
            {                   
                String tmp = new String();
                for (int j = 0; j < unApprovedFriends.length; j++) {
                    tmp = tmp.concat(unApprovedFriends[j].userName).concat(",");            
                }
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist));
                /*Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, 
                        getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist),
                        System.currentTimeMillis());*/

                Intent i = new Intent(this, WaitingListFriends.class);
                i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);              

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        i, 0);

                mBuilder.setContentText("Новый запрос друбы");
                /*notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist),
                                                "You have new friend request(s)", 
                                                contentIntent);*/

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


                NM.notify(R.string.new_friend_request_exist, mBuilder.build());         
            }
            else
            {
                NM.cancel(R.string.new_friend_request_exist);           
            }
        }

    }





    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {

        super.onResume();
        bindService(new Intent(ListOfFriends.this, MessagingService.class), mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(MessagingService.TAKE_MESSAGE);
        i.addAction(MessagingService.FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);

        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView.setMenuItem(item);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        else  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MaterialSearchView.REQUEST_VOICE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (matches != null && matches.size() > 0) {
                String searchWrd = matches.get(0);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchWrd)) {
                    mSearchView.setQuery(searchWrd, false);
                }
            }

            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }


    private void addNewFriend() {
        if (mFriendUserNameText.length() > 0) {

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    imService.addNewFriendRequest(mFriendUserNameText.getText().toString());
                }
            };
            thread.start();


            Toast.makeText(ListOfFriends.this, R.string.request_sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Log.e("ADD FRIEND", "addNewFriend: username length (" + mFriendUserNameText.length() + ") is < 0");
            Toast.makeText(ListOfFriends.this, R.string.type_friend_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                mFriendUserNameText = new EditText(this);
                android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setView(mFriendUserNameText);
                builder.setMessage("Добавить друга")
                        .setPositiveButton("Принять",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        addNewFriend();

                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Назад",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                return builder.create();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(snv)) mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(snv);
        if (mSearchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            mSearchView.closeSearch();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
       }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_light"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            style="@style/MaterialSearchViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
        android:id="@+id/listfr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"  />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_friend"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</FrameLayout>

    <com.appeaser.sublimenavigationviewlibrary.SublimeNavigationView
        style="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:snvHeaderLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:snvMenu="@menu/test_nav_menu_1"
        app:snvItemTypefaceFilename="planer_bold_webfont.ttf"
        app:snvHintTypefaceFilename="planer_reg_webfont.ttf"
        app:snvSubheaderItemTypefaceFilename="planer_bold_webfont.ttf"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Just study:)